# how to use tail and grep and get file name that have the result

Tags: bash, grep, gnu, tail

I am using tail and grep to find something like 'Apple' on multiple files
i need to get the file name that found the result in

```
tail -F files_name grep --line-buffered -e 'Apple' -e 'Orange' while read ;  do    while :;    do     echo -en "\007";     sleep 1;  done  ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Look to me like you overthinked.

```
grep 'Apple\|Orange' file1 file2
```

Searches for the string `Apple` or `Orange` in both `file1` and `file2`. `grep` will output the filename with `:` as separator. You can use  `grep -l 'Apple\|Orange' file1 file2` to print filenames only.

Comment: i cant use grep -l in the tail this will not bring the file name

"grep: No such file or directory" and this what happen when i use grep without -e

Comment: How do you use grep "in the tail"? You mean you want to _follow_ files (`tail -f`) and simultaneously `grep` for results?

Comment: The above code read the files continuously and when the grep get data it keep beeping .. i am reading from multiple  file at the same time i need to get the name of file that the result appear in

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -f *txt | awk '/^==> / {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next} {print a":"$0}' | grep -ni "Apple\|Orange"
```